# Upgrading Ram from 4GB to 8GB in packard bell tm80

Tags: laptop, memory

I own a Packard bell Tm80 laptop (this website has pulled up this info on recommended ram upgrade option):

http://www.crucial.com/uk/store/mpartspecs.aspx?mtbpoid=71500C5AA5CA7304

I have Samsung ram in the laptop as standard. Would this ram in second link be compatible... I bought 2 sticks off ebay for not far off the same price but they were causing the blue screen of death!!

http://www.flexxmemory.co.uk/laptop-notebook-memory/samsung-original-8gb-kit-2-x-4gb-204-pin-sodimm-ddr3-pc3l-12800-1600mhz-memory-module-m471b5173qh0-yk0/?ref=lexity&_vs=google&_vm=productsearch&adtype=pla&gclid=CMyWieb45r0CFSjpwgodo4gAGQ

The only diff I can see is that its PC3L-12800, instead of PC3-12800 ??? would this matter?
Any info or guidance would be great. Thanks in advance.
Lee

Answer (score 0):

- DDR3 or PC3 is the Standard Voltage memory module that operates at 1.50V (JEDEC compliant)
- DDR3L or PC3L is the Low Voltage memory module that operates at 1.35V (JEDEC compliant)

So yes, there is a differnce between those two. Other than that, PC3L should work on TM80.

Comment: So are you saying that the ram wouldn't be any good for this laptop? or would it still be OK to use??

Comment: It should be ok to use. On the other hand if you mix PC3 and PC3L, then I wouldn't be so sure. Did the system boot when you added new ram?

Comment: It did boot but when I got to the log in screen it flashed up the blue screen. (the ram off eBay wasn't samsung. I should have added sorry) it was "crucial" ram... a quick Google of the error codes all pointed to it being the ram. I could only think the ram was a bit poop.... If i was to buy the samsung ram DDR3L off this site as new do you think that would make the difference? Or should I just try looking for DDR3 ??

Comment: Well if the computer boots up then the RAM is supported. You can't boot off an unsupported RAM. Your wouldn't even see BIOS POST with unsupported RAM. There however might be either with RAM or with your OS configuration. You need to run memtest of livecd (http://www.memtest.org/) to check RAM for errors.

Comment: Ah ok. Well I think I will go ahead and buy the Samsung DDR3L ram then and see what happens. If Im still getting that blue screen coming up then IL run that memtest to see whats going on. and come back for help haha!!
Thanks for your help with this edvinas.me been a great help in understanding the difference